# AnyPoint MQ is giving error in prefetch configuration

Tags: mule, mq, anypoint-studio

I am trying to use prefetch in amypoint MQ but getting below error

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'anypoint-mq:provider'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/anypoint-mq":worker-threading-profile}' is expected.

Code :

```
<anypoint-mq:config name="Anypoint_MQ_Configuration" doc:name="Anypoint MQ Configuration">
        <anypoint-mq:prefetch fetchSize="1"/>
        <anypoint-mq:provider url="https://mq-us-east-1.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1" clientId="************" clientSecret="************"/>
    </anypoint-mq:config>
<flow name="testanypointmq1by1Flow2" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <anypoint-mq:subscriber config-ref="Anypoint_MQ_Configuration" destination="test" doc:name="Anypoint MQ"/>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <logger doc:name="Logger" level="INFO" message="Processing message received. #[payload]"/>
        <anypoint-mq:ack config-ref="Anypoint_MQ_Configuration" doc:name="Anypoint MQ"/>
    <logger doc:name="Logger" level="INFO" message="Message processed."/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Could you please answer the question, as soon as you added `anypoint-mq:prefecth` is throwing error or even after removing `anypoint-mq:prefecth` the line you are getting the same error?.

Comment: @star Thanks for the reply. It is throwing error when i add anypoint-mq:prefetch without this its working file with default config